# media query to align images

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I yesterday posted the question beneath in another post. It seems that it went messed up. (Posting date, comments... etc)  I hope it will go better with this post. I invite the commenters on the other post to look at it and comment aqain. Thanks in advance.

On my woocommerce single product page is a fairly large thumbnail shown. For one product a portrait image for another a landscape. I want to center the portrait ones in the surrounding div. I've tried it with `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to x%. This works fine for the portrait ones but the landscape ones are pushed to far to the right. The thumbnail images are floating to the left. Changing this will mess up the size.

In short, i want the portrait thumbnails centered and the landscape thumbnails standard (aligned to the left).

I was wondering can this be achieved with a media query or do I oversee a more simple solution. Please advice.

**EDIT**

Hereby the generated html/css code:

```css
.woocommerce img,
.woocommerce-page img {
     height: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
}
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images,
.woocommerce div.product div.images,
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images,
.woocommerce-page div.product div.images {
     float: left;
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
   <body class="single single-product postid-3758 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support custom-background woocommerce woocommerce-page custom-background-white custom-font-enabled single-author">

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
  <div id="content" role="main">

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="product-3758" class="post-3758 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail downloadable virtual taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-adri-2 product-cat-hellevoetsluis product-tag-adri product-tag-hellevoetsluis product-tag-zaandam instock">

      <div class="images">
        <a href="http://etc" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="SONY DSC" data-rel="prettyPhoto">
          <img width="567" height="853" src="http://placehold.it/567x853" class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="SONY DSC" title="SONY DSC" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="summary entry-summary">
        <h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">Photo 3</h1>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

          <p class="price"><span class="amount">&euro;xx,xx</span>  <small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">Exclusief BTW</small>
          </p>

          <meta itemprop="price" content="xx" />
          <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're not looking for a media query...but the CSS you posted doesn't seem to be related to the generated HTML at all...

Comment: @mevius: thank you for commenting. When I change the css rules above in the Chrome developer tools I see some changes applied to the images. Just not the right ones. When you referring to the .woocommerce classes, they are on the body tag of the page. I added the body tag.  The class .images is in the snippet, so is the div #content. Also the html img tag can be seen. Or didn't I understand you? If so, sorry about that. Still struggling to understand it all.

Comment: Update: When I run the snippet above I can change the styles in the developer tools. The placeholder for the image is centering beautifull when I switch off the float-left and apply a text-align to center. However in my own page this don't work. The image is blown up to 853 px wide.

Comment: The only way you can style portrait/landscape images differently is to use jQuery or JavaScript. You'll have to get the image dimensions on page load, and apply styles based on the proportions. There's no way to do this in CSS only, and it's not trivial. Specifically, you'll want to look into `.height`, `.width`, and `.css()`

Comment: Mevius, thank you very much. Because jQuery and JavaScript are really out of my scope at this moment I will try to find another, for me acceptable, lay-out.

Comment: @Mevius, I found a solution for my case. When interested, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

With respect for the commenters on this issue, I figured it out. At least for my situation.

First I edited template product-image.php. Of course I copied this file into my child theme first: child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php.

I wrapped the whole function in a `<p>` tag so the code looks like this:

```
<div class="images">


<p id="thumbnail-align" class="align-thumbnail">

<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

        $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_link  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        $image       = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), array(
            'title' => $image_title
            ) );

        $attachment_count = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );

        if ( $attachment_count > 0 ) {
            $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
        } else {
            $gallery = '';
        }

                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

    } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', wc_placeholder_img_src(), __( 'Placeholder', 'woocommerce' ) ), $post->ID );

    }
?>

</p>


        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>

</div>
```

Next I made some adjustments to woocommerc.css:

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images img,
.woocommerce div.product div.images img,
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images img,
.woocommerce-page div.product div.images img {
/*    display: block; -> can be deleted
      width: 100%; -> can be deleted
      height: auto; -> can be deleted*/
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
-webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
-moz-transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
-o-transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
}
```

It is in line 328 or so.

In woocommerce-layout.css is the following changed (line 39):

```
/*.woocommerce img, -> can be deleted
  .woocommerce-page img { -> can be deleted
     height: auto; -> can be deleted
     max-width: 100%; -> can be deleted
     } -> Can be deleted*/

/* and add the following:*/

p.align-thumbnail {
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right. You can achieve what you want using media query just change the `float:left` to `float:inherit` or `float:none`

here is the sample code.

```
    //when screen is resize to 300px
    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
            .woocommerce #content div.product div.images,
            .woocommerce div.product div.images,
            .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images,
            .woocommerce-page div.product div.images {
                 float: inherit;
                 //more styles here
             }
        }
```

it is ok if you don't include `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: This will not work because I am not resizing the window. I just want to change the alignment of the portrait thumbnail to be centered and the landscape ones to be left.